# Having alignment issues with an input form

Tags: css, html

I have added a small newsletter subscription text box to the footer of my website, and I'm having some alignment issues.

**Form code on its own:** http://liveweave.com/hAK1q6

**What it looks like on its own:**

[image]

**Footer code after adding form to it:** http://liveweave.com/k3L5h7

*Switch to **Split V** or **View mode** to fully see the Footer preview*

**Alignment issue:**

[image]

As you can see, padding appears all screwed up in the background, and the overall form is also not center aligned.

How do I fix this issues ?

Comment: `Form` is not taking the dimesions of the child elements. you must use `float` property to solve it on `Form` tag.

Comment: I noticed the first thing too .. How can I make `Form` take the dimensions of its child elements ? Also, where specifically are you suggesting I use `float` ?

Comment: You need to specify the size of the elements since you're floating them.

Comment: Tried using `float:left;` and `float:right;` in `.form-wrapper`, but that just further ruins the display .. Same as defining a style in the `Form` tag ..

Comment: that is not ruining your layout. that is the way you did the layout. there is a unnecessary margin, remove it. check my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give your `form-wrapper cf` `display:block;
this will solve (mostly) the appearance problem

and afterwords change some `margin` and `padding` of elements

Comment: Thanks ! Set margin to auto and it solved the empty spacing issue !

Answer (score 0):

Reduce margin value in `margin: 150px auto 50px auto` from `.form-wrapper` class and give `float: left` or `display` properties. such as `block` or `inline-block`.

Answer (score 0):

Add these style in `.form-wrapper`

```
margin: 0 auto;
display: block;
```

Check it here http://liveweave.com/d4cUjW.

**screenshot:**

[image]